# Ask for two symbols

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, vector-fields

I find several symbols in Differentiable Manifold. I list them in the following,
$$
\int_{\Omega}*(V)^b.
$$
I wanna ask about the meaning of $V^b$ so that I can calculate it.

For $*$, I guess it means the dual space of $V^b$.

Comment: The asterisk probably denotes the Hodge star, not the dual space. We can’t answer your question without seeing where you took this from. You could probably answer the question yourself if you simply looked more closely at the source you are reading.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is a vector space, $V^*$ is often used to denote the dual space, but in this case, the thing in the integral must be a differential form, so "$*$" probably means something like the Hodge-star operator. The superscript "b" doesn't mean anything to me except that maybe it means "apply hodge star b times," but that doesn't really make sense. More context is needed.

Comment: $b$ could be the musical isomorphism

Comment: Ah...so it's a transcription error combined with misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an answer in question 2683129, which says that:

You can avoid this problem using the musical isomorphism $\flat$, which is a map between the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and its cotangent. If this does not sound familiar, you may think that $\flat$ takes a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$ in input, and returns a dual form defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$. $\flat$ is defined through the metric $g$ as follows: $\flat(X) \mapsto X^{\flat}$, where $X^{\flat}$ is a 1-form now, and it acts on vector fields like this: $X^{\flat}(Y) = g(X,Y)$.
Using this definition you can compute $V^{\flat} = xdz + ydx$. In fact $V^{\flat}(V) = x^2+y^2 = g(V,V)$. Further, if $U = \sum_{i=1}^3 f_i(x,y,z)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, then $V^{\flat}(U) = g(V,U)$ (check!).

This paragraph may help me.